# How to checkout a tag from different remote branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-tag

I have a branch containing production configurations (called prod-conf for now) which follows a remote branch (feature-name-branch). When pulling from remote to perform an update would it be correct to run the following command ?

```
git pull origin feature-name-branch tag v1.0.0
```

I want to checkout a specific tag on the remote branch and merge the code on that tag with my production configuration. What I do not want happening is commits made AFTER the tag coming in .

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 git checkout prod-conf
 git merge v1.0.0
```

Tags are static markers. Unless you move the tag by deleting and recreating in, it will not give you any updates. In fact, a merge of a regular branch will do the same. You won't get any updates unless you do another merge explicitly.

Comment: So just to clarify, if the tag is moved and I execute the command `git merge v1.0.0` it will pull in the code from the updated tag?

Comment: whats the difference then between executing `git merge <other-branch>` and `git pull <other-branch>`

Comment: pull is fetch and merge (or rebase if specified or configured for that). Merge is either moving a branch forward or combining two diverged efforts of work.

Comment: no one can move a tag on you. You have to delete a tag and get it again if it was moved on the remote. All merging and reference manipulation is done locally. You only have a reflection of what was on the server the last time you fetched. Git is a disconnected model.